# Submiting a form that is inside a div with AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to submit a form using AJAX to stop the browser from refreshing the page.
The form is located inside a secondary page, that is called into the main page div ( similar to using a master page and the content placeholder ).

I have been trying several methods but I always reach the same problem. Whenever I try to submit the form, the response is the secondary page with the form, and I can't place the awnser inside the content div of the mainpage like intended.

Any tips on how to make this work?

```
    Main Page


    <div id="content"> Secondary page content goes in here loaded using AJAX</div>



    Secondary Page

    <form runat="server" id="formuser">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtusername" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtemail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <a href="#" onclick="document.formuser.submit()"> Submit Form </a>
    </form>
```

What I intend to do is Submit the above form, while staying in the Main Page and showing the response in the content div.
I need the form to be runat="server" so I can manipulate the data using the code-behind.

Comment: Could you show some code, please?

Comment: This is how the pages are organized.

Comment: The way this place is designed is that you post your answer as an Answer and then mark it as Accepted when you can (there's an interval before you can accept your own answer). Not by editing the question and putting [Solved] in its title. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the method I was using for the content load was building a xmlHttpRquest and it was conflicting with the response that I got from the jquery.

Answer (score 2):

Use some jquery:

```
       $('#SaveFormButton').click(function (e) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: $('#FormToSubmit').attr("action"),
                    data: $('#FormToSubmit').serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        //Whatever you want to do after the form has posted
                    },
                    error: function(data){
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
        });
```

Comment: Using this method to submit the form, how can I retrieve the data in the code-behind?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it. This way using e.preventDefault() you can use standard form markup and submit buttons.

http://jsfiddle.net/CcDPx/1/